# How can I write to the same line from a loop in Java

Tags: java

I wrote the following code to write a line in a text file, incrementing the contents by using a loop. The problem is that the method I'm using is writing each increment on a new line instead of appending.

```
for (int d = 10; d >= 1; d--) {        
    Path path = Paths.get("ScalModel.txt");
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    int position = 75;
    String extraLine = "MainAttack -OR-> {AttackNode" + d + "}";

    lines.add(position, extraLine);
    Files.write(path, lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8); 
}
```

The output I want to get is:

```
MainAttack -OR-> {AttackNode1, AttackNode2, AttackNode3, AttackNode4, AttackNode5, AttackNode6, AttackNode7, AttackNode8, AttackNode9, AttackNode10}
```

What I'm getting is:

```
MainAttack -OR-> {AttackNode1}
MainAttack -OR-> {AttackNode2}
MainAttack -OR-> {AttackNode3}
MainAttack -OR-> {AttackNode4}
MainAttack -OR-> {AttackNode5}
MainAttack -OR-> {AttackNode6}
MainAttack -OR-> {AttackNode7}
MainAttack -OR-> {AttackNode8}
MainAttack -OR-> {AttackNode9}
MainAttack -OR-> {AttackNode10}
```

How can I modify my code to get the expected result?

Comment: Specifying the charset as `UTF_8` is obsolete in `Files.readAllLines`. The `Files` class will always use `UTF_8` as default, by specification (in contrast to the old `File` class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of instructions inside the loop that you must put outside it. Here is like I'll do it:

```
Path path = Paths.get("ScalModel.txt");
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);    

int position = 75;
String extraLine = "MainAttack -OR-> {";

for (int d = 10; d >= 1; d--) {        
    extraLine += "AttackNode"+d;
    if(d==1) extraLine += "}";
    else extraLine += ",";
}

lines.add(position, extraLine);
Files.write(path, lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

If you do it in your way, you are reading and writing the file 10 times before getting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

try using a string build to build the string and then save it in one go

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("MainAttack -OR-> {");
int position = 75;
for (int d = 1; d <= 10; d++) {
    if(d!=10)
        sb.append("AttackNode" + d + ", ");
    else
        sb.append("AttackNode" + d + " ");
}
sb.append("}");
Path path = Paths.get("ScalModel.txt");
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
lines.add(position, sb);
Files.write(path, lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

fell free to edit

Comment: You forgot to actually use your `StringBuilder` `sb` anywhere, apart from building it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple example for your cause:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Path path = Paths.get("ScalModel.txt");
        try {
            String initialText = "MainAttack -OR->";
            for (int d = 1; d <= 10; d++) {
                initialText += " {AttackNode" + d + "}";
            }
            byte[] bytes = initialText.getBytes();
            Files.write(path, bytes);
        } catch (IOException ioE) {
            System.err.println("JVM reported an error! Take a look: " + ioE);
        }

    }
```